# HMAC SHA-384 in Java

Tags: java, sha

I am trying to translate this line of code in Python:

```
signature = hmac.new("1234abcd", b64, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
```

I am trying to get the hash of a string with a secret key using SHA-384. However, I am trying to do this Java, does anyone know how to do it?

Also, I am asked for a nonce. What are the requirements for that?

Comment: HMAC-SHA-384 is not the same as SHA-384; see my comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `MessageDigest` with a method to convert bytes to Hex:

```
private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA384";

private static String bytesToHex(final byte[] hash) {
    final StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
        final String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xff & hash[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hexString.append('0');
        }
        hexString.append(hex);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}

public static void main(final String... args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    final String nonce = "nonce";
    final String message = "test string";
    SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(nonce.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    final Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
    mac.init(signingKey);
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(mac.doFinal(message.getBytes())));
}
```

Comment: Where do you use the key? hex(HMAC_SHA384(base64(payload), key=api_secret)) does not take a nonce. It takes a payload and a key.

Comment: **HMAC-SHA-384** is not just SHA-384. See rfc 2104 and `javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA384")`

Comment: It's a bit confusing using nonce when you mean secret key, but otherwise great answer, cheers.